# Optimize sum(B[indices]) , which indices from top n selection in array A [CVXPY]

Tags: python, linear-programming, cvxpy

I have a model to predict customer ltv ( called `pltv`), and we want to find a best cutoff of  `pltv` to select customers with condition

- sum of revenue from top n customer, higher is better.

  - `objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum_largest( revenue[ y_pred >= cut] , n))`
- mean roi of top n customer, higher  is better ( which at least greater than 1.1)

  - `constraints = [ n >0 , cp.mean(roi[ y_pred >= cut]) > 1.1 ]`

Sample code:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

# Problem data.

t = 100
np.random.seed(1)
y_pred = st.norm.rvs(1, 0.5 , size=t)
roi = st.norm.rvs(1, 0.5 , size=t)
revenue = st.halfnorm.rvs(0, 0.5 , size=t)

n = cp.Variable(1)
cut = cp.Variable(1)

# Construct the problem.
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum_largest( revenue[ (y_pred > cut)] , n))
constraints = [ n >0 , cp.mean(roi[ y_pred >= cut]) > 1.1 ]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

result = prob.solve()

print(x.value)

print(constraints[0].dual_value)
```

But got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1acc60ebf5d7> in <module>
     21 
     22 # Construct the problem.
---> 23 objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum_largest( revenue[ y_pred >= cut] , n))
     24 constraints = [ n >0 , cp.mean(roi[ y_pred >= cut]) > 1.1 ]
     25 prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

The problem is `revenue` is `numpy.array` ,  which doesn't support `cvxpy.Variable`  cut .

Comment: I don't know of any solver that works with strict inequalities.  Just change all three of your strict inequalities to "greater than or equal"  `>` ---> `>=`

Comment: @AirSquid I have updated my question, change `>` to `>=` and found that `revenue` is `numpy.array` ,  which doesn't support `cvxpy.Variable`  cut .

Comment: I'm not a user of `cvxpy` (it looks great...I just don't have occasion to use it), but I suspect the issue is the logical indexing from `numpy` that you are trying to do.  I suggest you try to reformulated and instead of using `n` as a count, use a vector `x` of binary variables to indicate selection of `y_pred` using linear expressions and then sum this vector as the objective.  For instance, `y_pred >= cut * x`